# Problems Calling a Thread from another GUI Thread in QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am using QT to run a Traffic Project.
In one point, i create a thread who has to set some variables, wait sometime, set the variables to another value and die;
While this thread is waiting, other threads must keep running.
This is the thread class

```
//CLASS FOR CHANGING DYNAMIC LANE
class change_lane : public QThread
{
private:
    lane* dynamic_lane;
    lane_marking *lm_A;
    lane_marking *lm_B;
    time_t change_time;
    direction_way new_dir;
public:
    change_lane(lane *dl, time_t ct, direction_way new_dir) :
        dynamic_lane(dl), lm_A(dl->get_mark_A()), lm_B(dl->get_mark_B()), change_time(ct), new_dir(new_dir) {}
    void run()
    {
        QMutex mux;
        mux.lock();
        cout << "CHANGING DYNAMIC LANE" << endl;
        switch(new_dir)
        {
        case A:
            lm_A->change_status(changing_sw);
            lm_B->change_status(changing_df);
            break;
        case B:
            lm_A->change_status(changing_df);
            lm_B->change_status(changing_sw);
            break;
        }
        sleep(change_time);
        switch(new_dir)
        {
        case A:
            lm_A->change_status(same_way);
            lm_B->change_status(different_way);
            break;
        case B:
            lm_A->change_status(different_way);
            lm_B->change_status(same_way);
            break;
        }
        dynamic_lane->setDirection(new_dir);
        cout << "DONE: CHANGING DYNAMIC LANE" << endl;
        mux.unlock();
    }
};
```

This is how I call the thread;

This is inside another thread who is running in a while(true) loop;

The Thread is only called once because it sets the w->changing_lane to false;

```
//CHECKING IF DYNAMIC ROAD MUST CHANGE
    if(w->changing_lane == true)
    {
        direction_way temp_dirway = w->dyn_lane->getDirection();

         switch(temp_dirway)
         {
             case (A):
             {
                 change_lane cl_A(w->dyn_lane,5,B);
                 cl_A.start();
                 break;
             }
             case (B):
             {
                 change_lane cl_B(w->dyn_lane,5,A);
                 cl_B.start();
                 break;
             }
         }
        w->changing_lane = false;
    }
```

When I Press the button, I get this error:

[image: QThread Error]

And the program just stop responding.

In the Application Output, I get this error:

> QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running QMutex: destroying
>   locked mutex ASSERT failure in QThread::setTerminationEnabled():
>   "Current thread was not started with QThread.", file
>   thread\qthread_win.cpp, line 641

Please help

Comment: You're declaring a mutex *inside* your `run` function, mutex which is then locked and never given to someone else. Hence noone else is actually using that mutex. This makes all sorts of alarm bells ring in my head.

Comment: I tried with the QMutex and it didnt worked, same problem!

Comment: Maybe you should instantiate cl_A and cl_B somewhere outside the if statement (or even the while loop). However this means that you won't be able to pass parameters A, B to the constructor so you' ll have to define another class method for doing so

Comment: QThread is not a thread, but rather a thread controller. As such, inheriting from QThread is not the best way to use it, unless you want to change how Qt handles threads. A better method of using QThread is described [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation). In addition, if `lane_marking` derives from QObject, then changing `change_status` to a slot and emitting signals to call the function would negate the need for a QMutex.

Comment: You would benefit from reading [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) by Maya Posch.  Subclassing `QThread` is almost always the Wrong Thing to do.

Comment: Subclassing `QThread` is definitely not "almost alwas the Wrong Thing to do", as it depends a lot on what the thread does.
The worker object approach is fine for payloads that use the thread's event handling capabilities, it is just needless overhead of all the thread does it processing a single function that ends when it is done

Comment: @GabrielChavesBecchi you create your thread objects on the stack, inside a block of a switch-case. They get destroyed immediately after `start()` returns.

Comment: @KevinKrammer that did it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The parent thread controls child threads through the QThread object.Consequently the lifetime of the QThread object should be greater than the lifetime of the thread. After starting a thread you should wait for the thread to finish before deleting it. Call QThread::wait() to do this.

The mutex you've declared in the thread doesn't do anything as it is local to the thread. The point of a mutex is to use it from different threads to protect the data that is shared between them (so a mutex has to be accessible to more than one thread to be of any use).